# Create a key value pair in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, key-value

I have been trying to create a class which has a property for key value pair, I have tried the Dictionary keyword, but I need something like this:

```
ClassName clsName = new ClassName();

clsName.PropertyName.Add["Key"] = value;
```

I want it to be dynamic property so I can send any datatype.

Comment: Typically you'd talk directly to the class or property (`clsName["Key"] = value`, etc.), and not through an `Add`. As such, I'm not completely sure I understand what you're hoping to do. Do you just need to make an indexer on the class?

Comment: unlike javascript/python or other language, .NET is mostly strongly type thus made dynamic properties more difficult, however you can try to implement indexer in one of your property, however due to the nature of strongly type, the indexer might return object which you need to cast to other type

Comment: Its a little unclear what you are asking here. Do you want what essentially a `Dictionary` provides you but allows any type to be stored in the Value? If so than  us `object` as the Value of your dictionary, so use a Dictionary<string,object> and not a custom class. Are you trying to make a class that stores a representation of other classes? Then `PropertyName`'s type should be `Dictionary<string,object>`. Perhaps if you can show us some examples of how you would like to use/address/interact with this hypothetical class, we can show you how its made.

Answer (score 8):

If we suppose that `KeyValuePair` has as a key as a `string`, and a value as `int`, then you could try this:

`clsName.PropertyName = new KeyValuePair<string, int>("keyName", 2);`

You don't need to use the `Add` method. Actually, the latter makes sense when you have a collection and don't want to add an item to it. From what you have posted in your question, we can't say that this is your case.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to simply use the "HASHTABLE" its so much easier for you.Below is syntax.

```
    Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
    hashtable.Add("Area", 1000);
    hashtable.Add("Perimeter", 55);
```

1st parameter represents the key and 2nd one represents the value.So its the key value pair.

Comment: Link to official documentation for [C# Hashtable Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 3):

If you are after a basic class, for key and value, would

```
KeyValuePair<string, object>
```

work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but apparently your requirements can be met using a [generic Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), where the key type parameter is `string` and the value type parameter is `object`, i.e. you could use `Dictionary<string,object>` like this:

```
public class ClassName {
    public Dictionary<string, object> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
ClassName classObject = new ClassName();
classObject.Dictionary.Add("Key", new { "value" });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ClassName
{
  public KeyValuePair<string, object> PropertyName {get; set; }
}

var c = new ClassName();
c.PropertyName = new KeyValuePair<string, object>("keyName", someValue);
```

or, if you need to store multiple values, use `Dictionary<string, object>` as type of your property.

```
public class ClassName
{
    public ClassName()
    {
       this.PropertyName = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> PropertyName {get; set; }
}

var c = new ClassName();
c.PropertyName.Add("stringKey", anyValue);
```